# GKLeaderboard only returning localPlayer's scores

Tags: ios, gamekit

I'm trying to implement a scoreboard via GameKit, and I'm running into a problem where my query is only returning the scores for the localPlayer. I've set up two test users in itunes connect and am seeing this issue with both of them, it only returns the highest score for whichever player is currently logged in and doesn't return the other player's score at all. I have a table view which is populated by two arrays, one for player scores, one for player names.

```
- (void)loadGlobalHighScores
{
    GKLeaderboard *leaderboard = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
    leaderboard.identifier = @"MyLeaderBoardIdentifier";
    leaderboard.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeGlobal;
    leaderboard.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
    leaderboard.range = NSMakeRange(1, 100);

    [leaderboard loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
        NSMutableArray *playerIDs = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSMutableArray *playerScores = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (GKScore *score in scores)
        {
            [playerIDs addObject:score.playerID];
            [playerScores addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:score.value]];
        }

        self.playerScores = playerScores;

        [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:playerIDs withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error) {
            NSMutableArray *playerNames = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (GKPlayer *player in players)
            {
                [playerNames addObject:player.displayName];
            }
            self.playerNames = playerNames;

            [self.highScoresTable reloadData];
        }];
    }];
}
```

As far as I can tell I'm doing everything right, I'm not sure whether this is some issue with test user accounts or what.

Comment: Allow some time after you've created the test users ... I've seen some really long delays (12 hours or so).

Comment: Yeah, woke up this morning and it was working